# Trouble with restoring Postgres db running in Docker - getting "zsh: command not found: pg_restore"

Tags: postgresql, docker, shell, unix, pg-restore

I run Postgres from a local container, and do not have a local install of it. On macOS Ventura using Docker Desktop.

I can get the backup side to work just fine w/ the following command:

```
docker exec postgres-local-15 pg_dump -U postgres -F t dvdrental | gzip > /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar.gz
```

But I get:

> "zsh: command not found: pg_restore"

...when trying either of these methods to restore:

```
docker exec postgres-local-15 gunzip < /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar | pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental
```

-or- via network

```
gunzip < /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar | pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
```

Here's how I'm running pg locally, in Docker (macOS):

```
docker run --rm -v /Users/me/docker/postgres/15.3:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 --name postgres-local-15 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -d postgres:15.3
```

Could the "zsh" mean that it's looking on my local for pg_restore? I'm not the most sophisticated Docker guy - just utilizing what I found while searching.

Comment: BTW, in the future you might consider [unix.se] for questions that are more about command-line usage than software development.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair enough, though I think this may be more useful to developers working w/ the pg database, than those struggling w/ CLI usage. I suppose it would belong in either place. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's Happening

Shells split compound commands into simple commands before running them. Thus, your command line ends up being equivalent to:

```
{ docker exec postgres-local-15 gunzip < /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar; } |
  { pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental; }
```

Notice how `docker exec` is grouped into the simple command with the `gunzip`, while `pg_restore` is in a separate group. As this implies, the `docker exec` only applies to the `gzip` (which doesn't need to be run inside Docker in the first place), instead of applying to `pg_restore`.

---

#### How To Fix It (Option 1: Moving Only `pg_restore`)

You need to run `pg_restore` in Docker. You don't need to run `gunzip` in Docker.

Thus, you want the `docker exec` to come before the `pg_restore`, not before the `gunzip`.

```
gunzip </Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar |
  docker exec postgres-local-15 pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental
```

---

#### How To Fix It (Option 2: Moving The Whole Pipeline)

You can also run the whole pipeline in Docker, by starting a shell inside Docker that runs that pipeline.

```
docker exec postgres-local-15 \
  sh -c 'gunzip | pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental' \
  </Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar
```

Notice how the redirection is *outside* the quotes; this causes it to be run by your *local* shell before Docker is run, so it gets the file from your regular filesystem rather than looking for it inside the container.